# Can I play Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 on my PC with people playing on macs?

Tags: pc, macos, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Can PC Call Of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 servers interact with Mac servers so I can play with people who have Macs and not PCs?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this FAQ about the Mac version of Modern Warfare 3](http://blog.gameagent.com/aspyr-mac-faqs-call-duty-modern-warfare-2-call-duty-modern-warfare-3/):

> Do Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 and Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 for Mac feature multiplayer? What about cross-platform multiplayer?
>
> Cross-platform multiplayer, which allows Mac players to play with/against Windows PC players, is available for competitive multiplayer mode only at this time and is not available in Spec Ops mode.

So it would seem that PC players can play against Mac players, but can't co-op together.

Comment: tanx a bunch agent

Comment: @DRAGON_FYRE if you found this answer helpful, accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left and give the author some rep :)

Comment: Not that he doesnt have enough already

Comment: I wonder if a Mac was running Windows on bootcamp. Could that work for spec ops for a native PC and a Mac running bootcamp, like a coop lan party? Has anyone ever tried that?